# Quarto: Facilities for multiple **natural** languages/translation?

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, quarto

In the context of setting up a homepage using [Quarto](https://quarto.org), I am failing to find facilities and/or experiences doing so with multiple **natural** target languages.

I'm trying to achieve two versions of the same content (in my case one in English, one in German) within an identical navigational structure and a language name link to switch between them ...

Is this beyond the scope of Quarto? If not: how might this be achieved?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: There are some workarounds and suggestion about creating multilingual website and books discussed in [the issue #275](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/275) of quarto Github repo.

Answer (score 2):

Newer version of Quarto 1.2 available as pre-release (as of 09/2022) has a feature that should allow this more easily

https://quarto.org/docs/projects/profiles.html#language-content

This is the feature to use when looking to create a multi language book

Download for pre release can be done here: https://quarto.org/docs/download/

Comment: Nice and thank you for pointing this out!
However, this only solves half of my request: it renders possible to have alternate language content and switch between the two, but does **not** provide facilities to a) render them simultaneously and b) generate a **master switch**/link (on every (multilingual) page) that allows for navigational switching between the languages/translations.

Comment: I commented on this in the corresponding `github` issue: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/275#issuecomment-1248138655

Comment: Oh sure you're are right, definitely part of the issue - currently you would need to use project script feature (https://quarto.org/docs/projects/scripts.html) to build the two book, and at the same use a header include or something else to add a button for switching. Would be nice to have that built in, you were right to comment! thank you